# install django on subdirectory

Tags: python, django, apache2

I am running apache2 server on Ubuntu 14. Now I want to configure Apache to work with mod_wsgi to run Django on a subdirectory of a domain such as www.abc.com/lab, but I always fail to do that.

I have successfully installed Python by the way. I can do `python --version` which returns `Python 2.7.3`. The following are my steps of setting up:

1. I create a pylab folder under /var/www, inside has these files **init**.py, **init**.pyc, manage.py, settings.py, settings.pyc, and lastly urls.py
2. I then go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and create a lab file with the following contents:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>  
   ServerName /lab  
   DocumentRoot /var/www/pylab  
   <Directory /lab>  
   Options All  
   AllowOverride All  
   Require all granted  
   </Directory>  

   Alias /static/ /var/www/pylab/static/  
   <Location "/static/">  
   Options -Indexes   
   </Location>   

   Alias /media/ /var/www/pylab/media/   
   <Location "/media/">   
   Options -Indexes   
   </Location>   

   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/pylab/wsgi.py   
   WSGIDaemonProcess labapi python-path=/var/www/pylabprocesses=2 threads=15 display-name=Pylab   
   WSGIProcessGroup pylab   

   </VirtualHost>
   ```

But when I access www.abc.com/lab I only see a 404 error. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is it working with localhost/lab?

Comment: did not really try on localhost, as i dont use ubuntu on localhost, but wamp, i dont know if the set up is same or not

Answer (score 0):

You need a little tweak on your apache file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
ServerName www.abc.com/lab
Alias /lab/ /var/www/pylab
DocumentRoot /var/www/pylab  
<Directory /var/www/pylab>  
Options All  
AllowOverride All  
Require all granted  
</Directory>  

Alias /static/ /var/www/pylab/static/  
<Location "/static/">  
Options -Indexes   
</Location>   

Alias /media/ /var/www/pylab/media/   
<Location "/media/">   
Options -Indexes   
</Location>   

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/pylab/wsgi.py   
WSGIDaemonProcess labapi python-path=/var/www/pylabprocesses=2 threads=15 display-name=Pylab   
WSGIProcessGroup pylab   

</VirtualHost>
```

Change your code with above one and also symlink your config file which is now available under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` folder with `ln /etc/apache2/sites-available/source-file-name /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/target-file-name`

I hope you'll enjoy. :)

Comment: i have a question WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/pylab/wsgi.py currently i do not have wsgi.py under /var/www/pylab/ do i need to create that?

Comment: It is automatically created when you create a new project using django command. So I hope you don't want to create wsgi file manually.

Comment: i tried ur script, but still getting Not Found

The requested URL /lab/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at cloud.xxxx.com Port 80

Comment: Try now with new conf as above.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not create your project under /var/www. That's a potential security risk. Django is not PHP, it is not served as files by the webserver. Also, do not set DocumentRoot for the same reason.

The thing that determines where your Django app is served is the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive. So if you want to serve it under /lab, just set the directive to that:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /lab /<path>/pylab/wsgi.py
```

(where  is the path to your app that isn't /var/www).